# Google Calendar WeekView

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am developing an APP which needs

1. A WeekView layout displaying events stored(local db and sync with Google calendar)

2. Add Events in local db and events should be sync with local calendars(Google calendar)
That's all...i tried many things but not succeed...i tried AnCal but there is no sync option with Google calendar.[image]

i have AnCal it works fine and the thing is i need sync with google calendar but it doesn't...is there any AnCal with Google sync..are please suggest me with sample cal APP with google Sync...

Comment: maybe this will help you http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-calendarcontract-provider/

Comment: i have AnCal it works fine and the thing is i need sync with google calendar but it doesn't...is there any AnCal with Google sync..are please suggest me with sample cal APP with google Sync...